# Why does InputStream#read() return an int and not a byte?

Tags: java, inputstream

Why does [`InputStream#read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) return an `int` and not a `byte`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Because a `byte` can only hold -128 until 127, while it should return 0 until 255 (and -1 when there's no byte left (i.e. EOF)). Even if it returned `byte`, there would be no room to represent EOF.

A more interesting question is why it doesn't return `short`.

Comment: @dogbane, @BalusC - I guess because int is faster than short. The instruction set for short is rather limited, so the JVM would treat it like an int anyway. Reference : http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#7565

Comment: @Ishtar So what you're saying is that shorts are entirely useless, and will never be used by anyone? I have to say this is all very frusterating. 8 bits is literally a single number too short for this purpose. Can't they have it return the byte, and then just throw an exception on EOF? I know general java philosophy says not to use exception handling for control flow, but there's exceptions to everything.

Comment: If you return a `byte` (implicit cast) in an implementation of `InputStream` do not forget to apply `& 0xFF` to your return value (unless you return `EOF`). Otherwise you will return a signed value, which might work at first sight but is indeed utterly broken.

Comment: I think `short` is not used because it is not adjusted to java machine word, which is 4 bytes. `int` exactly fits one word, and working with int values faster, because avoids memory adjustments in results. For the same reason all classes in perm and instances heap are adjusted to 4 bytes too.

Answer (score 21):

It returns an int because when the stream can no longer be read, it returns -1.

If it returned a byte, then -1 could not be returned to indicate a lack of input because -1 is a valid byte.  In addition, you could not return value above 127 or below -128 because Java only handles signed bytes.

Many times when one is reading a file, you want the unsigned bytes for your processing code.  To get values between 128 and 255 you could use a short, but by using an int you will align the memory registers with your data bus more efficiently.  As a result, you don't really lose any information by using an int, and you probably gain a bit of performance.  The only downside is the cost of the memory, but odds are you won't be hanging on to that int for long (as you will process it and turn it into a char or byte[]).

Comment: It returns an int because when *EOF* occurs it returns -1. When an error occurs it throws an exception.

Comment: -1 is reserved for EOF, that should be the only reason because InputStream has another method int read(byte b[]), which reads the bytes as a chunk and returns them as byte array. int read() method can potentially return 257 values(256 potential byte values + EOF return statement)

Comment: @user207421 Might be late to the game, but I updated to remove the "error" bit.

Answer (score 5):

So it can return "-1" . It must do that when there is no more bytes to read.

You can't have it return a byte sometimes AND -1 for EOF/nobyte/whatever, so it returns an int ;)

Answer (score 3):

as the Java doc says in [InputStream#read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29), **The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255**. That is to say the byte value[-128~127] has been changed to int value[0~255],  so the return value can be used to represent the end of the stream.

Answer (score 2):

Because EOF (end of file or generally end of data) can't be represented using char.

Comment: You can not use byte and -1 because this value is correct and can occur in data.

Comment: It can't be represented using `byte`, because no out-of-band values are available. It *can* be represented in any data type wider than 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Appending to [BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4659706/907576):

- not a `byte` to allow *[0; 255]* as main capacity and additionaly *-1* as EOF result
- `int` is used to adjust result to machine word (one of the main requirements to I/O operations - *velocity*, so they should work as fast as possible!)

Exception is not used because they are significantly slow!

Comment: Exceptions are not used because they aren't necessary, an out-of-band value being available. However `readInt()`, `readShort()`, `readByte()`, `readChar()`, `readBoolean()`, `readFloat()`, `readDouble()`, `readObject()`, etc., do throw `EOFException`, because there is no out-of-band value that could be returned.