# Issue regarding the return value of the read() function in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why does InputStream#read() return an int and not a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659659/why-does-inputstreamread-return-an-int-and-not-a-byte/)
>
> [why return type of read() is integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430177/why-return-type-of-read-is-integer)

Hey I was just surfing java docs for material on I/O streams and just came across this question specifically in reference to the byte streams - If the input is a stream of bytes, why doesn't read() return a byte value ?

I scratched my head for some time but couldn't think of any strong answer to the question I would be grateful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `read` can return -1 as an indicator of end-of-stream (EOF) marker - i.e. no more bytes to be read from the stream.

More details: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29 . Specifically:

> If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been
>   reached, the value -1 is returned.

Comment: +1 You beat me by 28 seconds. Deleted my post.

Comment: hey thnxx for the link dude now i m able to understand the concept

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the fact that the `read` method can also return a value `-1` (when the end of the stream is reached). **So, you have to be able to store 256 values**.

**Some people think that the negative range of the `byte` is an issue, but that's actually irrelevant:** A byte has a range of `0 - 255`, but in java, a `byte` has a range of `-128 - 127`. But, you can still perfectly cast an `int` to a `byte` even when its value is greater than 127. It will just result in a negative value.

As a proof, there is a `read(byte[])` method that uses the `int read()` method internally and casts its result to a `byte` (after filtering possible `-1` values). So, this clearly tells us that if it wasn't of the `-1` value, java would use bytes after all.

A more difficult question: *"Why not a `short` instead of an `int` ?"* The answer is, java doesn't really like `short` that much. When performing basic operations, a `short` is often automatically casted to an `int`, introducing some kind of unnecessary overkill. **There is little or no gain in using shorts.**