# why return type of read() is integer?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why does InputStream#read() return an int and not a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659659/why-does-inputstreamread-return-an-int-and-not-a-byte/)
>
> [Issue regarding the return value of the read() function in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826875/issue-regarding-the-return-value-of-the-read-function-in-java)

As per the documentation the **read()** method of **java.io.FileInputStream** class reads next byte of the input stream, then why it's return type is integer, why not byte.

Is there any issue behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the manual:

> the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

you can't store `-1` in a byte, otherwise it would be indistinguishable from a valid read, so that's the reason.

Comment: Why can't you store -1 in byte ? It ranges from -127 to +128.

Comment: @Santosh: more precisely: you can't return it in a byte (but I think the *otherwise* part made that quite clear)

Comment: Of course you can return `-1` as a byte. `return (byte) -1;`. Of course the real answer is: you can not return *257* values with a byte, and you need the 257th values to signal the end of the stream.

Comment: @Bombe: *sigh* that's just what I said...  guys, don't you understand the difference between a comma and a period?

Comment: @Santosh the integer -1(0xFFFFFFFF) is a flag value and has to be different from all valid content, you can't store it in a byte since all byte values are used to represent content (0x00000000-0x000000FF)

Comment: @yi_H of course I knew what you were getting at but saying that you can not represent a `-1` in a `byte` is simply not true. :)

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have unsigned types. `read()` returns unsigned byte and the only way to represent it in Java is to use `int` type.

`byte` values are in `-128..127` range, while unsigned byte has values in `0..255` range.

Comment: If I writes byte b = -1; S.O.P(b);    It prints -1. If java doesnot support unsigned bytes, then it should give error?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. As already mentioned in other answers, there is a special return value `-1` which indicates end of stream. If we use Java's `byte` type which has values from `-128..127` range then we won't be able to distinguish `-1`-as-a-value from `-1`-as-end-of-stream.

Comment: in the range of integer also -1 is included. Then how it differenciates -1 -as-a-value from -1-as-end-of-stream

Comment: Look - `InputStream.read()` have to return 256 valid values + 1 invalid value as indication of end-of-stream. 257 values in total. Java's `byte` can hold **only 256** values. That is why they used `int`: `0..255` represents valid byte values, `-1` used for end-of-stream.

Answer (score 0):

The read() method of a FileInputStream returns an int which contains the byte value of the byte read. If the read() method returns -1, there is no more data to read in the stream, and it can be closed. That is, -1 as int value, not -1 as byte value. There is a difference here!