# Why is the return type of input stream off int?

Tags: java, byte, inputstream

Going off this question
 [Issue regarding the return value of the read() function in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826875/issue-regarding-the-return-value-of-the-read-function-in-java).

The answer to why the return type of the read method is an int is that is that the input stream can return -1(EOF marker)
My question is couldnt -1 be represented as a byte too? 
one bit (0 or 1 ) could signify positive or negative
the rest(7 bits represent the absolute value) - that is 0000001?

Comment: Look into signed and unsigned integers. An unsigned byte ranges from 0-255, not -1

Comment: yeah i read up on it. But theres no documentation on the input stream api that the input stream just works with unsigned(+ or 0) or signed(-,0 , or +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "byte" is an 8-bit value in a file.  There are 256 possible combinations of those 8-bits; those are all the values from 0 to 255, or from -128 to 127, however you want to view it.  `read()` has to be able to return all 256 of those values, since any one of them could be in a file.  `read()` also has to be able to return some special marker to indicate end-of-file.  Therefore, `read()` has to have the ability to return 257 distinct values, and it cannot do this if it returns a `byte`, since `byte` has only 256 possible values.

Comment: One could argue that a `short` is long enough though.

Comment: oh so the input stream is reading one byte at a time but won't actually read eof(it will just return it)

Comment: @merlin2011 It is.  But nobody uses `short` for much of anything, so there's no point in having `read()` return that.

Comment: @committedandroider Correct.  There is usually no special byte value _in a file_ to indicate the end of the file.

Comment: @ajb. Would a short be more efficient?

Comment: @committedandroider No.

Comment: @ajb from the last response, and the input stream api, input stream will return -1 if end of file is reached(no 257). Isn't a byte large enough(-128->127) to accompany -1? That was my original point

Comment: If a byte is -128 to 127, then that means a -1 byte could be in the file.  How would your program tell the difference between a -1 that it read from the file and a -1 indicating an EOF??  That's why `read()` needs to return **257 distinct values**.  And there isn't enough room for that in a `byte` no matter how clever you are.

Comment: @committedandroider If it were `short`, it would automatically be converted to `int` as soon as you use it as an operand in any operation (e.g. comparing it with -1). So it won't be more efficient than directly using `int`. (See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2)