# Why does InputStream read() return an int and not a short?

Tags: java

I was reading the [byte stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) trial and noticed the following statement

> Notice that read() returns an int value. If the input is a stream of
>   bytes, why doesn't read() return a byte value? Using a int as a return
>   type allows read() to use -1 to indicate that it has reached the end
>   of the stream.

The given reason for using an  `int` is that they can identify EOF by a -1. (seems shallow)

So the next bigger primitive type is `short` and it also supports -1 so why not use it?

From what i gather: (reasons to use `int`)

1. Due to performance `int` is preferred.
   [(this)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4659659/why-does-inputstreamread-return-an-int-and-not-a-byte)
2. `int` variable holds a character value in its last 16 bits (from
   [character
   trial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html))
3. Other more abstract streams would need to read more than just one
   byte (something that i guess (happens with character streams))

Are my reasons correct? Am i missing something (like error correction)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most important reason to prefer `int` over `short` is that `short` is kind of a second-class citizen: all integer literals, as well as all arithmetical operations, are `int`-typed so you've got `short`->`int` promotion happening all over the place. Plus there is very little or no argument *against* the usage of `int`.

Comment: ...and standard CPU architecture at the time java was devised was 32-bit, so `int` was (probably) the largest numeric that could be used at top speed, so why not use it because being larger it would have the longest life. I seriously doubt using `short` would save time or memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question :-) . It is true, that they had to use signed integer value type to represent EOF, but the preference of `int` over `short` is probably really just performance.

As I found on a different StackOverflow thread where this was discussed, the Java VM would automatically use `int` internally even if the definition used `short`.

The Java documentation states, that short should be used in large arrays and situations where memory really matters - source - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html . That is apparently no the case here, because we always get just one value.

Comment: But what about enforcing `short` overflow? That takes extra operations and comes for free with `int` (subject to native instruction support, of course, but the premise is that `int` is faster due to the *lack* of native `short` support).

Answer (score 1):

There is only one scenario where using `short` will give you an advantage: large arrays of short. To be sure, you can use them only when it is clear that the numbers to be stored fit the bounds.

In all other cases, it makes no real difference whether you have `short` or `int`. For example:

```
class A {
    short s;
    double d;
}
```

will not use less memory than:

```
class B {
    int s;
    double d;
}
```

because of alignment issues. So while the first one only has 10 bytes netto data, as compared to the second one that has 12, when you allocate an object it will still get aligned to some 8-byte boundary. Even if it is only a 4 byte boundary, the memory usage will be the same.

Comment: +1 jls does recommend using `short` over `int` only to save space