# How this cast actually works?

Tags: java, casting

I am revising the class `FileInputStream` and I am seeing some examples of reading a file that have made me wonder how the cast in those examples actually work. This is one of the examples:

```
public String read()
{
    String content = "";
    try
    {
        input = new FileInputStream(file);
        int chr = 1;

        // reads a byte and returns it as a integer. 
        // Returns -1, if there's no more bytes to read.
        while ((chr = input.read()) != -1)
            content += (char) chr;//CAST

        input.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why read returns an integer instead of a byte? What are the advantages?
2. How exactly the cast works from integer to a char?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659659/why-does-inputstreamread-return-an-int-and-not-a-byte

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to note about reading files, from the JavaDoc for [`FileInputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) -

> **Returns:**
>       the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.

1. `-1` Would be  a valid `byte` value. But by using an `int` they can reserve it to as special `eof` value. That value happens to be `-1`, but that is why they return an `int`.
2. For all other values the cast to `char` is mapped to [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) code units.The JavaDoc to [`java.lang.Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) says in part

> An `int` value represents all Unicode code points, including supplementary code points. The lower (least significant) 21 bits of int are used to represent Unicode code points and the upper (most significant) 11 bits must be zero. Unless otherwise specified, the behavior with respect to supplementary characters and surrogate char values is as follows:

And `utf-8` fits into that value range with the first 24 bits being 0 and the last 8 bits being your `byte` as `int` 0 - 255. So, the cast converts the stream of `byte`(s) into a `String` using the ISO-8859-1 encoding, and because that overlaps with the first 256 (0-255 inclusive) Unicode code points it becomes human readable text.

Comment: The question refers to the InputStream API, but this answer relates to Reader API. The former works with bytes, the latter with characters.

Comment: @MartinEllis +1 Thank you so much (I welcome *constructive* criticism)! Edited. I trust this is better?

Comment: The answer still refers to characters and code points. I don't think they're relevant with an InputStream. Or rather, if they were relevant, the InputStream would probably be wrapped with a Reader.

Comment: @MartinEllis How else do you define how Java widens the 8-bit byte to a Unicode character?

Comment: OK, ignore my previous comment. I was confused that the duplicate question asks something slightly different. It might be worth mentioning that the code parses the stream into a String using ISO-8859-1, because it overlaps with the first 256 Unicode code points.

Comment: @MartinEllis Edited. Yes, that's what I was trying to say.

Comment: I would suggest one further small edit, in item 2 of the list, to replace "it" with "the cast to `char`". As it is now, it sounds like this answer says that the value from `FileInputStream.read()` returns -1, or a byte of data that's mapped to UTF-16 code units.