# Why do i have to typecast to byte when reading from a fileinput stream?

Tags: java, file-io, casting

I'm currently working my way through an online java lessons where the topic is about reading and writing using input stream. Specifically, the lesson demonstrates using a shift entered by the user to encrypt a image file, and then decrypting the same image file using a negative shift.

However, in the code provided, i do not understand what the critical line actually does, and why it does what it does. From what i can make of it, it reads a byte from the `FileInputStream` and typecasts it to a byte, and then adds the shift to it before writing it out via the file outputstream. However, since i am already reading a byte from the `FileInputStream`, why do i have to typecast it to a byte again?

I would really appreciate anyone shedding some light on this.

Thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadingAndWritingStreamsNonText {
    public static String imgFilePath = "C:\\JavaProjects\\BinaryStreams\\src\\MIM_BINARY_MEME.jpg";
    public static String imgFilePath2 = "C:\\JavaProjects\\BinaryStreams\\src\\data.bin";
    public static String imgFilePath3 = "C:\\JavaProjects\\BinaryStreams\\src\\MIM_BINARY_MEME_Decrypted.jpg";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a shift to encrypt/decrypt the file:");
        int shift = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            PrintStream ps = null;

            if (shift > 0) {
                fis = new FileInputStream(imgFilePath);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imgFilePath2);
                ps = new PrintStream(fos);
            }
            else {
                fis = new FileInputStream(imgFilePath2);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(imgFilePath3);
                ps = new PrintStream(fos);
            }

            boolean done = false;
            while (!done) {
                //read in the file
                int next = fis.read();
                if (next == -1) {
                    done = true;
                }
                else {
                    //encrypt or decrypt based on shift
                    **ps.write(((byte) next) + shift);** <--- this line
                }
            }

            ps.close();
            ps = null;
            fos.close();
            fos = null;
            fis.close();
            fis = null;
        }
        catch (IOException ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Operation Completed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`InputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) returns an `int` instead of a `byte`.

Note that this method will return -1 when the end of the stream is reached, and a value in the range 0 to 255 if a byte was read, as the API documentation says:

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.

An `int` needs casting to be converted to a `byte` because an `int` is 32 bits, while a byte is only 8 bits. You can't do a narrowing conversion (which throws away the upper 24 bits of the `int`) without a cast.

Answer (score 4):

> it reads a byte from the fileinputstream and typecasts it to a byte, and then adds the shift to it before writing it out via the file outputstream. However, since i am already reading a byte from the fileinputstream, why do i have to typecast it to a byte again?

Because `read()` returns an `int`, which might be -1, indicating end of stream. If it isn't -1, it is a value in the range 0..255, which you have to typecast to `byte` to get the `byte`, in the range -128..127. If this process wasn't followed it wouldn't be possible to indicate end of stream via the return value.

Answer (score 2):

`FileInputStream.read()` returns an int, not byte, because of this: [Why does InputStream#read() return an int and not a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659659/why-does-inputstreamread-return-an-int-and-not-a-byte)

But you want to shift exactly 8 bits of data, and int is larger (32 bits). So you need to cast it to byte.